# Decoding error: typeMismatch "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am struggling to decode a JSON. I am trying to decode my JSON with

```
let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Country.self, from: data)
```

Here's the codable struct:

```
struct CountryData: Codable {

    let translations: Name
    let capital: String
    let currencies: [String]

}

struct Name: Codable {
    let fr: String
}

typealias Country = [CountryData]
```

Here's the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Norway",
        "topLevelDomain": [
            ".no"
        ],
        "alpha2Code": "NO",
        "alpha3Code": "NOR",
        "callingCodes": [
            "47"
        ],
        "capital": "Oslo",
        "altSpellings": [
            "NO",
            "Norge",
            "Noreg",
            "Kingdom of Norway",
            "Kongeriket Norge",
            "Kongeriket Noreg"
        ],
        "region": "Europe",
        "subregion": "Northern Europe",
        "population": 5176998,
        "latlng": [
            62.0,
            10.0
        ],
        "demonym": "Norwegian",
        "area": 323802.0,
        "gini": 25.8,
        "timezones": [
            "UTC+01:00"
        ],
        "borders": [
            "FIN",
            "SWE",
            "RUS"
        ],
        "nativeName": "Norge",
        "numericCode": "578",
        "currencies": [
            "NOK"
        ],
        "languages": [
            "no",
            "nb",
            "nn"
        ],
        "translations": {
            "de": "Norwegen",
            "es": "Noruega",
            "fr": "Norvège",
            "ja": "ノルウェー",
            "it": "Norvegia"
        },
        "relevance": "1.5"
    }
]
```

Error I got:

```
Decoding error: typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

I couldn't figure out what I have done wrong, I have tried checking my struct with app.quicktype tool but couldn't spot any issue. I am new to Swift, it will be great if someone can give me some advice how on how to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: Works for me... Is the JSON you showed here the actual JSON you get?

Comment: `codingPath: []` — most likely you *real* JSON is not array on the **top** level.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, I copied from the example here:  https://rapidapi.com/apilayernet/api/rest-countries-v1?endpoint=53aa5a09e4b051a76d24136a

Comment: @user28434 Sorry I don't understand, what do you mean by top level? I have checked with Postman too, the above JSON is what it returns

Comment: @Einn_a, `JSON` is hierarchical (like a tree). And on top, in its root it has one, and one element only. You assume it's array(`[]`), but it's object(`{}`) instead.

Comment: your code is fine, I can get decodeData

Comment: @Einn_a could you add this line `print(try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data))` 
right above the `let decodedData` line and check in the console to see if the data is same as the one you've posted here.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct

[image]

I already try it in playground

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I think I have figured out where the problem is, there's nothing wrong with this struct but the app is not getting back the expected JSON, instead it receives an error